# Pass data from block to controller

Tags: blocks, magento-1, controllers

When I try to call block method in controller it returns me null value but when I run same block method in view(.phtml) it returns right value.

I'm trying to get number of posts in controller so I can add rel prev and rel next in header. Since I cannot edit header from block i need this data in controller.

Is this possible, can i pass data from block to controller?
By calling **getPosts** function in view i'm getting all posts. I want to do same think but in controllers because i need to edit header of page.

Here is Block class:

```
 <?php
/**
 * @category    Fishpig
 * @package     Fishpig_Wordpress
 * @license     http://fishpig.co.uk/license.txt
 * @author      Ben Tideswell <help@fishpig.co.uk>
 */

class Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Post_List extends Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Post_Abstract
{
  /**
   * Renderer and template information for post types
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $_postTypeTemplates = array(
    'post' => 'wordpress/post/list/renderer/default.phtml',
  );

  /**
   * Cache for post collection
   *
   * @var Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Resource_Post_Collection
   */
  protected $_postCollection = null;

  /**
   * Returns the collection of posts
   *
   * @return Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Mysql4_Post_Collection
   */
  public function getPosts()
  {
    return $this->_getPostCollection();
  }
  /**
   * Returns the collection of posts
   *
   * @return Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Mysql4_Post_Collection
   */
  public function getPostsHomepage()
  {
    return $this->_getPostCollectionHomepage();
  }

  /**
   * Generates and returns the collection of posts
   *
   * @return Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Mysql4_Post_Collection
   */
  protected function _getPostCollection()
  {
    if (is_null($this->_postCollection) && $this->getWrapperBlock()) {
      $this->_postCollection = $this->getWrapperBlock()->getPostCollection();

      if ($this->getPagerBlock() && $this->_postCollection) {
        $this->getPagerBlock()->setCollection($this->_postCollection);
      }
    }
    var_dump(count($this->_postCollection));die();
    return $this->_postCollection;
  }

  /**
   * Generates and returns the collection of posts
   *
   * @return Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Mysql4_Post_Collection
   */
  protected function _getPostCollectionHomepage()
  {
    if (is_null($this->_postCollection) && $this->getWrapperBlock()) {
      $this->_postCollection = $this->getWrapperBlock()->getPostCollection()->addCategoryAndPostIdFilter(array(), array(2, 80, 75, 1, 12, 79));

      if ($this->getPagerBlock() && $this->_postCollection) {
        $this->getPagerBlock()->setCollection($this->_postCollection);
      }
    }

    return $this->_postCollection;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the parent block of this block
   * This block can be used to auto generate the post list
   *
   * @param Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Post_List_Wrapper_Abstract $wrapper
   * @return $this
   */
  public function setWrapperBlock(Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Post_List_Wrapper_Abstract $wrapper)
  {
    return $this->setData('wrapper_block', $wrapper);
  }

  /**
   * Get the pager block
   * If the block isn't set in the layout XML, it will be created and will use the default template
   *
   * @return Fishpig_Wordpress_Post_List_Pager
   */
  public function getPagerBlock()
  {
    if (!$this->hasPagerBlock()) {
      $this->setPagerBlock(false);

      if ($pager = $this->getChild('pager')) {
        $this->setPagerBlock(
          $pager->setPostListBlock($this)
        );
      }
    }

    return $this->_getData('pager_block');
  }

  /**
   * Get the HTML for the pager block
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function getPagerHtml()
  {
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
  }

  /**
   * Retrieve the correct renderer and template for $post
   *
   * @param Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Post_Abstract $post
   * @return Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Post_List_Renderer
   */
  public function getPostRenderer(Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Post_Abstract $post)
  {
    if (!$this->hasPostRenderer()) {
      $this->setPostRenderer(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('wordpress/post_list_renderer')
          ->setParentBlock($this)
          ->setExcerptSize($this->getExcerptSize())
      );
    }

    return $this->_getData('post_renderer')
      ->setPost($post)
      ->setTemplate(
        $post->getPostListTemplate() ? $post->getPostListTemplate() : 'wordpress/post/list/renderer/default.phtml'
      );
  }

  /**
   * Ensure that the post list handle is set (adds the pager)
   *
   * @return $this
   */
  protected function _prepareLayout()
  {
    $this->getLayout()
      ->getUpdate()
      ->addHandle('wordpress_post_list');

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
  }

  /**
   * Ensure a valid template is set
   *
   * @return $this
   */
  protected function _beforeToHtml()
  {
    if (!$this->getTemplate()) {
      $this->setTemplate('wordpress/post/list.phtml');
    }

    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add relevant codes to your post.

Answer (score -1):

Accessing Block class in controller/Model file is deprecated. You can write the code about to get the numbers posts in Hepler class and make use of it.

Comment: could you please show the source of deprecation ?

Comment: in Mage.php, getBlockSingleton

Comment: I couldn't find @deprecated tag over there.  I looked into `1.9.3.1`. I dont think such deprecation does exist in M1 controllers. You can often see lot of codes in core controllers which actually invokes blocks and alter them.

Comment: I have added from EE 1.14, in Mage.php line number 525,
* Deprecated, use self::helper() *